# Delete old commit message

Tags: git

Here at work some co-workers are using Tower to interact with Git. Tower automatically creates commit messages when merging and also when squashing commits. Because of that, we now have a couple of commit messages from a few days ago, that are over 100MB in size. This is has been causing some real issues with my IDE using close to 4GB RAM and making it inoperable at times.

My question is, how can I change just the commit messages of those 2 commits. I have tried `git rebase -i <hash#>` and when the interactive rebase opens, I put `reword` by one of the commits and press `:wq`. The problem is that it seems as though I may have to go through 100+ commits and resolve conflicts for it to rebase. I know I must be doing something wrong.

Anyone have any idea how to do this without screwing up my current branch and also without have to resolve merge conflicts for a ton of previous commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not using `rebase` correctly: `git rebase -i <hash#>` will replay your current branch on top of `<hash#>`, which doesn't seem like what you're trying to do.

Assuming the commit message in question is on a feature branch (other than `master`), you probably want to do something like this:

```
git checkout my-branch
git rebase -i $(git merge-base master HEAD)
# Use reword as you did previously
```

This will perform a `rebase` in-place, allowing you to adjust the commits in `my-branch` that aren't also in `master`.

Answer (score 1):

**Rewriting the most recent commit message**

You can change the most recent commit message using the `git commit --amend` command.

**Commit has not been pushed online**

If the commit only exists in your local repository and has not been pushed to GitHub, you can amend the commit message with the `git commit --amend` command.

1. On the command line, navigate to the repository that contains the commit you want to amend.
2. Type `git commit --amend` and press **Enter**.
3. In your text editor, edit the commit message and save the commit.

The new commit and message will appear on GitHub the next time you push.

more read on this Github published article [here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/).

Hope helped :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the OP is describing a situation where the commits were pushed numerous days ago...